# Is it possible to set an overall seed for generating blocks on regtest mode?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I am using bitcoin core on regtest mode to simulate sending transactions.

Is it possible to set an seed for things like generating blocks or signing transactions, so that you can recreate an exact chain of events with the same block hashes and signatures?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question completely..
In the current version you generate blocks to an address.
What would you set a seed for

Comment: Right now if i start up bitcoind in regtest mode, and the first thing I do is generate a block so that the block height is 1, the block hash will be unique. Is there any way of starting up bitcoind so that it would give me exactly the same block hash each time? (I realize now it would probably mean setting the time to something fixed).

Answer (score -1):

Generation of blocks uses the proof of work algorithm that includes a nonce that ensures randomness, if we could somehow recreate all these things the whole system of cryptocurrency would break down. The short answer is no.

Comment: Downvoted. I don't see how this is related to the question.